# Null spaces and range

Tags: linear-algebra

Find null space and range space of the next linear map: $$T(a_n)=a_{n-1}-2a_{n-2}$$
So this is my idea $$T:S_n\to S_n$$
First find $$a_{n-1}-2a_{n-2}=r-2=0$$ to find the root $$r=2$$ Then define $$\operatorname{null} 
 T=\{a_n\in S_n :\alpha 2^n=0\}$$
and $$\operatorname{Img} T=\{b_n\in S_n :\alpha 2^n=b_n\}$$
Can you please check the idea. I want to know if I´m in the right path and if not a little bit of criticism would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is in your best interest to explain your notation.

Comment: what is $a_n$? I mean, what vector space is $S_n$?

Comment: I´m using linear recurrence. Vector space of successions.

Comment: The notation is very unclear.